# Windows 10 "We couldn't complete this update" error

Tags: windows-10

So while I was using my laptop, Windows decided to update itself. Now I'm stuck on "We couldn't complete this update. Undoing changes" and it keeps rebooting. No error was shown. I can't go into safe mode I kept pressing F8 but nothing happens. I also tried pressing SHIFT + FN + F8 and SHIFT + F8 but nothing happens. How do I fix this?

My laptop is an Acer aspire 5750.

Answer (score 0):

boot from the Windows 10 DVD go to the Windows Recovery Options and run the command prompt and run this:

```
DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions
```

*(replace C: with the drive where you installed Windows 10)*

This reverts all pending update operations. Now you should go back to Windows 10. After the reboot, go to `C:\Windows\Logs\` and share the `CBS` folder. I'll look what fails and add it later to this answer.

Comment: I solved the problem by removing my laptop battery and inserting it again. I then booted up the laptop and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing my laptop battery and inserting it again. I then booted up the laptop and the problem was fixed.

Comment: this is really a strange fix, but nice to hear that it worked

Comment: hehe, I talked to a Microsoft support person. He told me that apparently if you plug out the battery and insert it again, it acts like a hard reset.